# Eclipse Debugger: Variable view when using nested Java HashMap, ArrayList

Tags: eclipse, java

EDIT2: Ok, this is most likey an Eclipse Debugger issue. adding the follwing code gives my what i would expect. So there is no odd behaviour of the code, only the debugger makes me think, there was one. (Eclipse Indigo Build id 20110615-0604)

```
Object bla1 = map.get("String3");
Object bla2 = map.get("String4");
Object bla3 = map.get("String1");
Object bla4 = map.get("String2");
Object bla5 = map.get("innerMap");
Object bla6 = map.get("list");
```

EDIT: This is NOT an order Problem! I know what a HashMap is and i dont care about the order. The problem is, that put("list", list) will not create a new HashMap entry, it overwrites an old one. put("liste", list) will add a new entry. Neither "list" nor "list" entries exist at adding time. Please do not tell me "You are a Newbie" answers, i you have not debugged the code example (using jdk1.6.0_24).

I am using jdk1.6.0_24 as my Execution environment and encountered a problem that seems very Strange to me:

```
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add("A String 5");
    list.add("A String 6");

    Map<String, Object> aMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    aMap.put("String7", "A String 7");
    aMap.put("String8", "A String 8");
    list.add(aMap);

    Map<String, Object> innerMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    innerMap.put("newString", "Yet another new String");
    innerMap.put("bool", false);
    innerMap.put("long", 3L);
    innerMap.put("Integer", 3);

    List<Object> anotherList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    anotherList.add(1);
    anotherList.add(1L);
    anotherList.add("Another String");
    anotherList.add(true);

    List<Object> aList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    aList.add(2);
    aList.add(2L);
    aList.add("Yet Another String");
    aList.add(false);

    anotherList.add(aList);

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("String3", "A String 3");
    map.put("String4", "A String 4");
    map.put("String1", "A String 1");
    map.put("String2", "A String 2");
    map.put("innerMap", innerMap);
    map.put("list", list); //here it happens
    //map.put("list0", list); //here it happens also
    //map.put("list1", list); //here it happens also
    //map.put("list2", list); //this will work, when you use this line and comment out all 'here it happens' lines
    map.put("anotherList", anotherList);
```

Depending on the key value of the new Entry, Object list (which is an ArrayList) is either handled as I expect it (added to map on a new position) or: list will be added to map at a position where one of the prior added objects was alredy sitting. The already existing object is not overwritten, it is accessable via next.

Can anybody explain, what happens here? Would you expect this behaviour? I haven't tried an other java version yet.

Comment: Please read the documentation about the data structures you want to use before actually using them.

Comment: I did. Maybe you see what i try to explain, when you debug my example.

Comment: Debugging your code, there does not seems to have any problem in it. Here is the toString of your `map` variable: `{String3=A String 3, String4=A String 4, String1=A String 1, String2=A String 2, list=[A String 5, A String 6, {String7=A String 7, String8=A String 8}], innerMap={newString=Yet another new String, bool=false, Integer=3, long=3}, anotherList=[1, 1, Another String, true, [2, 2, Yet Another String, false]]}`. There is `list`, `anotherlist` and `innerMap` all in the same map.

Comment: It seems to be a Eclipse Debugger issue. I edited the Question.

Comment: Cannot reproduce what you're describing. It might be a compilation problem. Do you have "Build Automatically" checked under "Project" menu? If so, keep it checked and do a manual "Clean".

Comment: clean did not change anythin. Two friends reproduced this issue on two different machines now.

Answer (score 1):

The keys of a `HashMap` don't have a predictable order. If you want to keep the insertion order, use a `LinkedHashMap`, if you want the keys orderd (natural order), then look for a `TreeMap` (both are part of the Collection API)

Comment: This is not about order in the Map. I use the Map and dont care about the order. when i put("list" list) it some kind overwrites an object in the map. when i put ("liste", list) it does not overwirte another entry, it creates a new one

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about iteration order of the map? For `HashMap` the iteration order is not specified and is likely to be quite random (which of course it really isn’t, you just can not easily see the order at first glance because it depends on the objects’ hash values); if you need a guaranteed order, use a `SortedMap` such as `TreeMap`.

Comment: No, i am not talking about the order. When i put("list", list), then it will not only be at another position, it some kind of overwrites an exisitng entry NOT named "list"

Comment: I find that very hard to believe. I will try your code and see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: It is hard to believe, since it is not true. See edited Question. But maybe you can confirm it is a debugger issue (variables view).

Comment: I did expect this: I can not reproduce it. The code as it is above results in 7 objects in the map. If I remove the line comments there are 10 objects in the map. Everything is as it should be.

Comment: Well, the variables view sometimes does strange things, yes. One thing I have noticed: when a variable changes (to a non-null value) it is still shown as `null` until you step over the next line; only then does it show the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Last sentence of first paragraph.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Sounds like you are new to Java.  Get to know the Javadoc and use it constantly, it is your friend.

Comment: No, this does not explain the behavoiour. It is not an order Problem. I dont care about the order.